# Creating PHP parralel treatments from a getResult doctrine request

Tags: php, multithreading, symfony, doctrine, queue

I would like to do some kind of multi threading in a PHP8/Symfony6 environement which would work as follow:

I'm making a doctrine request which serve around a million of rows

I would like to create multiple parralel processes to treat those rows simultaneously.
My request is made with a getResult() which serve doctrine objects.
Is there a way I could create threads with an array of objects as parameter. And then process to create thread as long as my "queue" is filled with datas?

I found some informations about "pthreads" or "popen" but I'm not sure its still relevant as the topics are a bit old

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could look at Symfony's process component https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html ot the messenger component https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html

Comment: In either case, I would recommend not trying to pull back all the data from the database in one go, but get your worker threads to extract batches

Answer (score 0):

In this case, one of the things that Doctrine does is hydrate a class with the content of the data, so all of the millions of records are converted in classes and keep them in memory, so there are several recommendations:

1. Avoid use getResult in huge queries. instead of that, try with pagination and clear the entity manager if you are gonna perform some operations of this objects like:

```
public function paginate(int $start = 0, int $offset = 10): Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('student');
    $qb
       ->where($qb->expr()->isNull('student.schoolRef'))
       ->setFirstResult($start)
       ->setMaxResults($offset);
    return new Paginator($qb, true);
}

src/Service.php

$start = 0;
$offset = 100;
do {
    $i = 0;
    $students = $this->studentRepository->paginate($start, $offset);
    foreach($students as $student) {
    //do stuff
      ++$i;
    }
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $this->entityManager->clear();
} while ($i == $offset);
```

2. use a direct query using while:

```
<?php

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    *
FROM user u
SQL;

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();

while ($user = $statement->fetch()) {
    // print_r($user);
}
```

You could also fetch all users at once with the `fetchAll` method, but beware that if your query returns too many users, you could run out of memory. With the `while` loop above, you are only fetching one user in to memory at a time so the memory performance is better.

```php
<?php

// ...

// all users are in memory here
$users = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    // print_r($user);
}
```

Also as someone commented you can use

- [Symfony Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)
- [Symfony Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html)